# Can I use table-cell as a stand alone style?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

When using the CSS `display:table-cell` on an element, is it somehow preferred/required that it's parent elements have `display:table-row`, and `display:table`?

Can this stand alone in a document?

```
<div style="display:table-cell;">content</div>
```

Or in table tag fashion, should I nest some additional parent tags with appropriate styles?

```
<style>
.table {display:table;}
.tr {display:table-row;}
.td {display:table-cell}
}
</style>
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">content</td>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using display:table-cell is a good trick for laying out elements on the same line (especially since no white space is rendered between them) but I'm wondering if it is just that: a trick. Can I expect that the behavior may change at some point in the future?

Is this stylistically incorrect? It appears to display consistently across all (modern) browsers (IE7 and lower doesn't support `display:table-cell`)

```
<style>
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:0px 5px;
  background-color:#aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<div>
  <span class="cell">option one</span>
  <span class="cell">option two</span>
  <span class="cell">option three</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If it works in the browsers you need it to work in, use it. There are no gods on Mt. W3-lympus that will strike you with a bolt of lightning.

Comment: What about IE 14 or Mozilla Fire Sloth? (browsers from the future)

Comment: @Matthew Not even SO can predict the future.

Comment: @millimoose `display:inline-block` renders white space between elements: http://jsfiddle.net/KjXhx/ which is gross

Comment: @Matthew Yeah, I noticed it seconds after posting the comment. Anyway. By IE14 hopefully the flexbox layout will be finalized which I believe might be able to do this sort of layout "cleanly".

Comment: @Matthew In fact, it indeed does with minimal code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uyEvx

Comment: I can only expect it will be around IE14 before Microsoft implements things like `flex` and `box`... in the mean time, it seems like table-cell might be a good fit for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are free to do it either way.  If table and table-row elements are not provided, anonymous ones will be inserted for you (as long as the browser follows the W3C specification).

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

> Any table element will automatically generate necessary anonymous
>   table objects around itself, consisting of at least three nested
>   objects corresponding to a 'table'/'inline-table' element, a
>   'table-row' element, and a 'table-cell' element.

Keep in mind that anonymous elements cannot be styled.  This is only an issue if there isn't enough content within your table-cell elements for them take up 100% of their parent's width.  In this case, only a table element is necessary, you can drop the table-row.