# How To Limit Div By Auto Height of Another Element Using Only CSS

Tags: html, css

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892790/how-to-auto-set-the-height-of-a-div-using-the-height-of-another-div), but I want to set the height of some set of aligned elements to be the height of the "shortest" one/minimum height if they all used automatic for height. I know how to do this with Javascript, but I have no idea if it's possible with just css, but it would be neat.

Comment: can you clarify what you need in your own question?

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with just CSS. The ability to match the max height (like in the question you linked to) is simply a side effect of how tables work. Nothing to my knowledge is going to try and hide content by default.

Comment: Try Foundation Equalizer: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html